# How to have dynamic endpoint mapping and wsdl definitions for Spring Webservices?

Tags: spring, web-services, soap

I have a webservice with endpoint defined as below -

```
@Endpoint
public class MyEndPoint {

    private static final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(MyEndPoint.class);

    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService"; 

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart="mySoapRequest")
    public @ResponsePayload MyResponse handleMySoapRequest(@RequestPayload MyRequest mySoapRequest) throws Exception{
        //do something here
          mySoapRequest.getUserId();
    }

}
```

Then I have the request object

```
@XmlRootElement(name="mySoapRequest" , namespace="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class MySoapRequest {

    @XmlElement
    private String userId;

    @XmlElement
    private String userName;


    }
```

This is my static wsdl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:sch="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://mycompany.com/ls/schemas" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/ls/schemas">
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema xmlns:tns="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/timeServices" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService">

    <xsd:element name="mySoapRequest">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="userId" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="userName" type="xsd:string"/>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>


</xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
-----
---some more code which is not relevant here--

  <wsdl:service name="mySoapService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:mySoap11" name="mySoap11">
      <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:mySoap12" name="mySoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://localhost:8080/soap/soap-ws/mySoapService/"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

My challenge is to have dynamic endpoint mappings so that I should be not bound to this url **http://localhost:8080/soap/** when making request.
I would like to test webservice on dev server, qa server and then deploy to production without changing code.
I can define the endpoint url in properties file/dbase and then based on environment , would like to transform the request to appropriate url.

My questions

1. Can I modify the endpoint NAMESPACE_URI at run time ?
2. Can I transform the path in wsdl (maybe WsdlDefinitionHandlerAdapter) ?
3. Can I change the namesapce in MySoapRequest ?